# How to link static lib without full path?

Tags: cmake

```
root
 +-- main.cpp
 +-- CMakeLists.txt
 +-- liblib1.a
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(testlib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(testlib main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testlib
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/liblib1.a
)
```

How to link without `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` like:

```
target_link_libraries(testlib
    lib1
)
```

How to make `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` path visible to CMAKE `ld`?

---

BTW, below didn't work `error: cannot find -llib1`

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(testlib
    lib1
)
```

Comment: You can copy the library into your system library path.

Comment: @squareskittles Is possible to add the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` make it the same as system library path?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`target_link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_directories.html?highlight=s):

> Specify the paths in which the linker should search for libraries when linking a given target.
>
> ...
>
> NOTE: This command is rarely necessary and should be avoided where there are
>   other choices. Prefer to pass full absolute paths to libraries where
>   possible, since this ensures the correct library will always be
>   linked.

```
target_link_directories(testlib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: this did work...but I just want to make the certain path be visible to `ld`

Comment: I do not understand you. How does this not make the path visible to the linker? You want to just add the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf`? Use LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: `target_link_directories(testlib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` will automatically find the libs, but I want only `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` visible to the linker, then I specific the link libs manually not automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the directory of lib in CMake is `link_directories`.

I didn't get works because **`link_directories` have to put in front of `add_executable`**.

like this:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(testlib main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testlib
    lib1
)
```

---

BTW, I found a great tutorial talks about this kind of CMake dependency usage.
https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/

Comment: Use of the [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) command is not recommended, it even says in the documentation. You should prefer the target-based commands, as used in KamilCuk's answer.

Comment: @squareskittles Yes, I understand, I actually using the lib with the specific path, this question just because of curiosity. Thanks for reminding me.